# what is the best audio and video format that best fit my ipad air?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, applications, video

i have some videos that i would like to convert to become suitable for my iPad air and iPhone 4s, but i can play around with the audio and video format (ex: video codec, video bitrate, frame rate, video aspect, audio codec, audio bitrate, sample rate)  which i don't know which best suits them. i am using "any video converter" to do this, if any one has any idea how to do this please tell.

Answer (score 1):

iOS Devices only support natively MP4 H.264.

By natively I mean, it is the only format with hardware acceleration. Using hardware acceleration instead of software decoding will save you some battery time.